# Color the border of points and adjust the shapes based on categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

How do I color the border of the points based on the `rank` column? I also want to assign different shapes for `sex`.

```
library(tidyverse)

data(Salaries, package="carData")

col <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("#ff816f","#f1f1f1","#004252"))(1000)

ggplot(Salaries, aes(x=yrs.since.phd, y=salary, color=rank, shape=sex) ) +
  geom_bin2d(alpha=0.5) +
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=col, na.value=NA, guide="legend")
```

Current plot:

[image]

Comment: Isn't that already happening? Try `geom_bin2d(alpha=0.5, linewidth = 2) +` for thicker lines.

Comment: @JonSpring sorry, what I meant is color using a specific palette, not the random colors

Comment: Pick a `scale_color_*` function with the palette you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach making minimal changes to your code. I use `stat_bin2d` so I can switch the tiling geom from tiles to points, and then change the point shape to 21, which is one of the shapes with separate color and fill aesthetics. Then I can map fill to `..count..` which is calculated by `stat_bin2d`.

(I'd note that a major shortfall of this approach is that many bins have multiple combinations of sex / rank which you are asking to display at the same x/y location, leading to overplotting and hiding much of the data. Pick fewer variables to show at once. Just because you can show 5 doesn't make it a good idea...)

```
ggplot(Salaries, aes(x=yrs.since.phd, y=salary, color=rank, shape=sex) ) +
  stat_bin2d(geom = "point", aes(fill = ..count..), 
             shape = 21, size = 2, stroke = 1) +
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=col, na.value=NA, guide="legend") +
  scale_color_viridis_d()
```

[image]

I would probably approach this differently to have more control over the binning and aesthetics, by pre-calculating the counts using dplyr and feeding those into ggplot2.

The underlying problem here is that you're trying to show too much. Note here that most locations have multiple combinations (up to 6 possible) of rank and sex, which I've attempted to make some room for using jitter on the position. I would highly recommend concentrating on perhaps only 3 variables at a time -- 5 is visually noisy and almost impossible to interpret.

```
Salaries |>
  dplyr::count(yrs.since.phd, salary_rnd = round(salary/1E4)*1E4, rank, sex) |>
ggplot(aes(yrs.since.phd, salary_rnd, colour = n, fill = rank, shape = sex)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 1000), 
             size = 3, stroke = 1) +
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Male" = 21, "Female" = 22)) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors=col, na.value=NA, guide="legend") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21)),
         color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21)))
```

[image]

Comment: When I use `scale_color_manual`, it seems to override `scale_fill_gradientn`, meaning that the points is completely filled with the colors specified in `scale_color_manual`.

Comment: (Side note, mapping 5 variables to one plot is almost certainly overambitious if your goal is clear communication. Note that in your current version you have multiple observations overlapping each other in each bin, we're just seeing the top ones.)

Comment: What does the `count` represent?

Comment: Mapping shape, fill, and color at once leads to challenges in legends because you have to define what the other aesthetics should look like while the one in question changes. I think that's why you're seeing that issue with scale_color_manual. See my answer for the `override.aes` part to fix this.

Comment: Can I replace `scale_fill_viridis_d` with a custom palette? I tried `scale_color_manual(values=c("#003f5c", "#bc5090", "#ffa600"))` but it raised `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`

Comment: You probably mean `scale_fill_manual`? In my 2nd example colour is mapped to `n` which is continuous and so it needs a continuous scale.